# Group all tests and display in browserstack

Tags: protractor, browserstack

I am running my protractor tests on browserstack and noticed that the tests I run are marked as separate entries. I want to group them all into a single build. 
I have added `build` capability to my protractor config file. But it doesn't seem to help. 
Attaching my protractor configuration field. Appreciate your help.

Thanks

```
exports.config = {
  specs: [
    './src/**/*.e2e-spec.ts'
  ],
  browserstackUser: xx,
  browserstackKey: xxx,
  multiCapabilities: [{
    browserName: 'chrome',
    os: 'Windows',
    os_version: '10',
    'browswestack.debug': true,
    project: 'protractor'

  }, {
    os: 'OS X',
    os_version: 'High Sierra',
    browserName: 'Safari',
    'browswestack.debug': true,
    project: 'protractor'
  }],
  build_number: 'local',
  maxInstances: 2,
  SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false,
  directConnect: false,
  connectionRetryCount: 3,
  connectionRetryTimeout: 90000,
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200',
  framework: 'jasmine',
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
    print: _.noop
  },
  onPrepare: () => {
    tsNode.register({
      project: path.join(__dirname, './tsconfig.e2e.json')
    });
    let reporter = new SpecReporter();
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(reporter);
  }
};
```

EDIT : I fixed the problem. I was using build_number instead of build.

However , when I run the tests I noticed that the tests are getting appended. For instance if I run 5 tests , I could only see the last test as executed in browserstack. How should I fix this ?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I fixed the issue. I was using build_number instead of build.

Answer (score 0):

Open a session on Automate Dashboard and under 'Input Capabilities', check if 'build' is visible.